# ckeditor automatically visually resize dropped image

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, django-ckeditor

Is there a way to automatically visually resize dropped image in the ckeditor4 (I am using 4.7)? Often, the dragged image is too big in dimension. True, it is resizable, but the user need to go all the way to right bottom corner to resize it. What I would like to have is: once the image is dropped, it automatically resize to max_width: 600px, and height changes accordingly. Is this possible? BTW, I am using django-ckeditor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that ckeditor4 (likely after version 4.7?) has default function to take server-returned image width and height in Json response (as in [uploadimage plugin.js](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/major/plugins/uploadimage/plugin.js)).

```
                onUploaded: function( upload ) {
                    // Width and height could be returned by server (https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13519).
                    var $img = this.parts.img.$,
                        width = upload.responseData.width || $img.naturalWidth,
                        height = upload.responseData.height || $img.naturalHeight;
```

By default though, Json response only returns `uploaded`, `filename`, and `url` [doc here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_upload.html).

So, in django-ckeditor, I had to modify `ImageUploadView` in `ckeditor_uploader views.py` to return `width` and `height`. The way I accomplish this is a bit ugly. If anyone has a better idea, please do edit my answer. BTW, this approach worked for both dropped image and pasted image.

modify views.py as follow:

add 
`from PIL import Image` to the top.

modify ImageUploadView as follow:

```
class ImageUploadView(generic.View):
    http_method_names = ['post']

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        """
        Uploads a file and send back its URL to CKEditor.
        """
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['upload']

        backend = registry.get_backend()

        ck_func_num = request.GET.get('CKEditorFuncNum')
        if ck_func_num:
            ck_func_num = escape(ck_func_num)

        filewrapper = backend(storage, uploaded_file)
        allow_nonimages = getattr(settings, 'CKEDITOR_ALLOW_NONIMAGE_FILES', True)
        # Throws an error when an non-image file are uploaded.
        if not filewrapper.is_image and not allow_nonimages:
            return HttpResponse("""
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction({0}, '', 'Invalid file type.');
                </script>""".format(ck_func_num))

        filepath = get_upload_filename(uploaded_file.name, request.user)

        saved_path = filewrapper.save_as(filepath)

        url = utils.get_media_url(saved_path)

######to get width and height of image

        image = Image.open(filewrapper.file_object)
        print(image)

        if image.width > 800:
            factor = 800/image.width
            new_width = int(image.width*factor)
            new_height = int(image.height*factor)

            width = new_width
            height = new_height
        else: 
            width = image.width
            height = image.height

##############
        if ck_func_num:
            # Respond with Javascript sending ckeditor upload url.
            return HttpResponse("""
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction({0}, '{1}');
            </script>""".format(ck_func_num, url))
        else:
            _, filename = os.path.split(saved_path)
            retdata = {'url': url, 'uploaded': '1',
                       'fileName': filename,
########## return width and height
                       'width': width, 'height': height} 
            return JsonResponse(retdata)


upload = csrf_exempt(ImageUploadView.as_view())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [Enhanced Image](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/image2) plugin, checkout my suggestion/answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081025/2073776

Comment: your solution in the linked post is for image upload using file browser (click picture icon, and upload). Thanks! What I am asking here is for drag-and-dropped image. Which seems to use different upload method [link](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_upload.html) andouse Json response. Any idea how to proceed?